# Laravel doesn't view a page with a CSS Admin LTE

Tags: php, html, css, laravel, routes

I have issue with my code, because when I'm trying open link with 2 arguments like:

```
Route::get('/admin/users', 'AdminController@users');
```

My css from Admin LTE is not loading and then I have not styled site. When is only 1 argument like

```
Route::get('/admin', 'AdminController@index');
```

then everythink is working fine. What I did? I just copied all HTML lines from Admin LTE and delete something what I don't need. Stylesheet is pluged in HTML file. Can you help me what should I do in this case? Any advice how to run it correctly? Thank you in advance.

It's Laravel 7.*

Comment: try this <link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">

Comment: Show us your html

Comment: @castle It works. Thank you so much